# MongoDB get documents between two number fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm developing internet store and have been facing next problem. I've got next **ProductCategory** schema

```
const ProductCategorySchema = new Schema({
  _RANGE_START_: Number,
  _RANGE_END_: Number
});
```

Here is **Product** schema

```
const productSchema = new Schema({
  _ID_: Number,
  _SORT_: Number,
  _ART_: String,
});
```

For example, field _RANGE_START_ = 65000, field _RANGE_END_ = 66000, both of fields are numbers. 
Product field *SORT* = 65302.
The question is, how can I query the database to get categories of product?
I have been trying next queries:

```
const productCategory = await ProductCategory.find({
    // First
    $where: `this._RANGE_START_ >= ${product._SORT_} || this._RANGE_END_ < ${product._SORT_}`,
    // Second
    $and: [
      {
        _RANGE_START_: {
          $gte: product._SORT_,
        },
      },
      {
        _RANGE_END_: {
          $lte: product._SORT_,
        },
      },
    ],
    // Third
    _RANGE_START_: {
      $gte: product._SORT_,
    },
    _RANGE_END_: {
      $lte: product._SORT_,
    },
  });
```

With all options I've got empty array

Comment: if you try to retrieve where range start is greater or equal than, and range end lower or equal than, you'll be false. Start must be lower and end greater if you want value between start and end...

Comment: @matthPen thank you so much! you save me a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

```
     const ProductCategorySchema = new Schema({
     _RANGE_START_: Number,
     _RANGE_END_: Number
     });

  var RANGE={
    sort:65300,
};
product.find({$and:[{$or:[{_RANGE_START:{$gte:RANGE.sort}},{_RANGE_END:{$lte:RANGE.sort}}]}]},function(err,data){
     console.log('adad',data);
});
```